# How get field from set of fiels defined in CTE field alias?

Tags: postgresql

```
with t as (
 select
 (select t1 from table1 t1 limit 1) t,
 'foo' x
)

select 
 t.id, t.code, x 
from t
```

How can i get t.id and t.code in result query?

Comment: what's `t.code` ? - I don't see that defined in the CTE .Post some sample data and expected result to say what you are expecting.

Comment: t.code - column in table1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an extra parenthesis to go within the resultset.

I have renamed your CTE to distinguish that the parenthesis refers to the table selected within the CTE, and not the CTE itself.

```
with cte as (
 select
 (select t1 from table1 t1 limit 1) t,
 'foo' x
)

select 
 (t).id, (t).code, x 
from cte
```